# How to reload the jqgrid renderer after ajax post call?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am using renderer in jqgrid which displays the button for particular column , now I want to change the button to text when user press the button. How will I be able to change the rendere r to label from button to text at runtime using javascript ?

Comment: the best way depends from *how* you created the button in the column. You should append your question with JavaScript code which shows what you do. Moreover it's unclear which "ajax post call" you mean. In the text of the question you write only about pressing a button by the user. You should describe more clear what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery

classname = common for all button

```
$(".classname").click(function(){
       $text = $(this).text();
       $(this).replaceWith($("<lable></lable>"));
});
```